# Connection not secure with heroku custom domain?

Tags: node.js, ssl, heroku, https

I've set up paid dynos for my heroku app. The SSL certificate works on my-app.herokuapp.com but when I go to my custom domain I get your connection is not private.

I'm using godaddy as my domain provider. I have my CNAME set with name: www and value: my-app.herokuapp.com

It works on http but not https.

Answer (score 1):

Your SSL certificate has to be registered to the domain name you're serving from.  If it "works" on my-app.herokuapp.com then you need to purchase an SSL cert for your custom domain.  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint#acquire-ssl-certificate

Answer (score 0):

Adding a Heroku instance to a subdomain is done by pointing the subdomain to Heroku's dns instance, not the app.

Example:

- Create a CNAME record
- Host: `subdomain` (ex: **explore**.main-street.com)
- Target: `herokudns` (ex: autumn-sunset-1495.herokudns.com)

Read [Heroku's docs here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#configuring-dns-for-subdomains).